# Position text properly below a centered image

Tags: html, css

I used the following code to center my image and to format my text.

```
IMG.center {position:fixed; top:40%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}

h1 span {display: block;}

h1 span.major {font-family:Avenir Lt Std; font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; border:0px solid black; padding:0px; text-align: center;}

h1 span.minor {font-family:Avenir Lt Std; font-size:20px; border:0px solid black; padding:0px; text-align: center;}
```

And display the elements as such. However, the text keeps floating to the top of the page.

```
<body>

<IMG class="center" src="picture.png" alt="icon" style="width:596px;height:166px;"> 

<h1>
    <span class="major">some text</span>
    <br>
    <span class="minor">some text</span>
</h1>
</body>
```

Why does the text floats to the top? and how does one move the text below the image?  The key is to center the image first and print the text relative to the image (i.e. below).

```css
IMG.center {position:fixed; top:40%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}

h1 span {display: block;}

h1 span.major {font-family:Avenir Lt Std; font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; border:0px solid black; padding:0px; text-align: center;}

h1 span.minor {font-family:Avenir Lt Std; font-size:20px; border:0px solid black; padding:0px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<IMG class="center" src="picture.png" alt="icon" style="width:596px;height:166px;" /> 

<h1>
    <span class="major">some text</span>
    <br>
    <span class="minor">some text</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Did you notice your body tag is broken and img is not a valid tag?

Comment: Always give fallback fonts in case people don't have your font or your embedded font is broken in some browsers. Like so: 'font-family:"Avenir Lt Std", Arial, sans-serif';

Comment: Thanks I originally left it out intentionally because it was reformatting my questions.  I updated it now. Thanks.

Comment: You have a fixed position image and a relative positioned text. Put the text and image in one container and center that.

Comment: Doesn't the fixed position just position the image relative to the web browser? If I include the text in the container, then the image would be out of place?

Comment: @HC exaclty, the fixed position just position the image relative to the web browser, but your text is still part of the relative layout, so it starts from the default position and not relative to the image tag.

Comment: @Samy. I see.  I'm new to this.  So how do you put it all in one container and only center the image in the container? (basically the desired result would be the image in the middle of the broswer with the text offset below. If you center the container, then the image will be slightly above the middle no?

Answer (score 0):

Having `position:fixed` makes the image relative to the browser window instead of the other elements on the page, and removes it from the "flow" of the page. From the `h1`'s perspective the `img` is positioned separately/out of the flow, and the `h1` is put at the top of the page.

You could set `position:fixed` on the other elements and align it, but here's a simpler approach that you might prefer (setting left and right `margin` on a `display:block`):

HTML:

```
<div class="center-text">
    <img class="center" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <p>Caption</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-text {
    text-align:center;
}
img.center {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:blue
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mw6djz8n/

(Note: you may want to swap `margin:auto` for `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto` if you want to use top or bottom margins)

More info on CSS `position`:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), [learnlayout](http://learnlayout.com/position.html), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), [Codecademy Lesson](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh/3/1)

Comment: Thanks.  One of the reason I used position fixed is because it also center the picture both vertically and horizontally.  Your solution puts the picture on the top of the page. How can you also center it vertically?

Comment: if you have .center on the image already, try setting height and width on the image, ie. `<img src="picture.png" width="320" height="240" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

Used [flexbox](http://demosthenes.info/blog/css/flexbox) to center the elements and [min-content](http://demosthenes.info/blog/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-Min-Content) to frame the elements. I made height on the `body` (`101vh`) and `main` (`101%`) because it makes scrolling in iOS8 a little smoother.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CENTERED</title>
</head>

<body>
  

  <style>
    html {
      font: 500 16px/1.5 'Avenir Lt Std';
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body {
      height: 101vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: #111;
      color: #DDD;
    }
    
    main {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      height: 101%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .center {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      self-align: center;
      border: 3px double white;
      flex 0 0 100%;
      margin: 50% auto;
    }
    
    .center > * {
      flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
    
    .frame {
      border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
      background: #222;
      margin: 0;
      width: -moz-min-content;
      width: -webkit-min-content;
      width: min-content;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: bolder;
      border: 1px solid brown;
      padding: 1px;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .desc {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 3px 1px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .caption {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    
    img {
      display: table;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
    }

  </style>
  
  <main>
    <figure class="center frame"> <img src="http://placehold.it/569x166/000/fff.png&text=This+is+the+Picture"
      alt="icon" style="width:596px;height:166px;" />
      <figcaption class="caption">
        <h3 class="title">This is the Title</h3>
        <p class="desc">This is the description.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```